# window.pageYOffset shows different values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I can easily go up and down in web pages using java script. I made a function for that :

```
function moving() { 
var move=window.pageYOffset;
move=move+950;
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:  move  },0);
}
```

Then I have some pictures. All pictures have same height. I have to move down every `950px`. It works great but after 3 times it will move more than `950px`.

I use `alert(move);` for giving me `pageYOffset`. It shows me :

950 ... 1900 ... 2850 ... 3800 .. 4750 ... 5700

So it goes `950px`. But however I have same images with same height it won't go the same location as the last picture. Something like it goes more than `950px` after the third time and everything will go wrong.

**Update** :

here is code for images that i have :

```
    <div align="center">
  <table width="1132" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images/Look_01.jpg" width="566" height="849" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/Look_01.jpg" width="566" height="849" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div align="center"><img src="images/arrow_up.png" width="47" height="58" border="0" usemap="#Map" class="hover" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="4,4,44,54" href="#" onclick="up()"/>
  </map>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<img src="images/arrow_down.png" width="47" height="58" border="0" usemap="#Map2" class="hover" />
<map name="Map2" id="Map2">
  <area shape="rect" coords="3,4,45,53" href="#" onclick="move()" />
</map>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div align="center">
  <table width="1132" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images/Look_01.jpg" width="566" height="849" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/Look_01.jpg" width="566" height="849" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then it goes on with the same pictures and same height. But It won't go the same situation of the last picture however it goes every `950px`.

It's like a photo album. All pictures have the same height so when I want to go down I would like to go down as the same situation as the last picture. But it messed up. After third time it will go down more than `950px` and it goes more and more.

I really hope you underestand what I'm meaning.

Please help me so that I can fix that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's getting out of sync because the value of `pageOffsetY` will get out of sync as you go further down the page.  Perhaps post some of your markup, and I can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. You have to define `var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;` outside the function scope.

Also as you knoe because of value of `pageOffsetY` it's getting out of sync. So you need to minus `15px` each time you get down.

So change your code to this :

```
var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
function down(){ 
var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
scrolled=scrolled+950;
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:  scrolled  },2500);
scrolled = scrolled - 15;
}
```